# Sending Email from web form using php

Tags: php, html, email

I wrote a php script to sent email from web form when use clicks a button. The mail is working but it show this warning message in the inbox : "this mail might not have been sent from example@example.com". Here is my php code:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])){

    $to = 'indra.web@satenterprise.com';
    $subject = 'Booking';

    $message = 'Name:' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= 'Email:' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= 'Phone:' . $_POST['message'] . "\r\n\r\n";

    $headers = "From:" .$_POST['email'] . "\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';

    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if($email){
        $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: $email";
    }

    $success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if(isset($success) && $success){ ?>
         <h4 style="font-family: Arial; color: #777777;">Thank You, your mail has been sent. We will be in touch with you very soon.</h4>
    <?php }else{
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem sending your message";
    }
}
?>
```

is there any way to do away with this disturbing message?
Thank you

Comment: If your email is reaching the sender , then why not using `errror_reporting(0);` ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen `error_reporting()` is a PHP function. The warning message is appearing in the message in the recipients InBox where there's no PHP involved.

Comment: Sorry i thought that the error was thrown once triggering email. Thanks :)

Comment: @Indra : What is the from address you having in the `$_POST['email']` because some servers handle that too. Try using real email address

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I have used genuine email address in $_POST['email].

Comment: Short Answer: You're using the email address supplied by the user as a `From:` address, but sending it from your server. The receiving mail server is detecting that and flagging it to the recipient as a possible problem. Some mail servers will block such a message. Use an email address that's valid on your PHP server as the `From:` address and just include the user's email address in the body of the message. Longer Answer:There is, however, much more to this as SPF and DKIM checking come into play. Good luck.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Thanks. Its working. There is no warning message anymore. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The below code it will work try this..

```
<?php
$contact_name=$_POST['contact_name'];
$contact_email=$_POST['contact_email'];
$contact_phone=$_POST['contact_phone'];
$contact_message=$_POST['contact_message'];
$to_email = 'xxx@domain.com'; //you can give email id to whom you need to send
$html = 'your custom body of the mail';
$subject = 'you subject' . $contact_message;
$message = $html;
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ABC' . "\r\n"; //DONT GIVE SPACE IN "ABC"  //you can replace your value but no space.. if u give space you can get email in spam only..
$response = mail($to_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($response)
{
    echo "Mail sent";
}
else
{
    echo "Not sent.. Try later";
}
?>
```